# $J \subset I(V(J))$ where $J$ is an ideal.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The textbook says it's by definition, but as I see it the inclusion should be reversed should it not?

I mean $I(V(J))= \{ f\in k[x_1,\dots, x_n]: f(a_1,\dots ,a_n)=0 \text{ for an arbitrary element } (a_1,\dots, a_n)\in V(J) \}$.

Now $V(J)$ is the set: $V(J)=\{ (a_1,\dots ,a_n)\in k^n: \text{ for an arbitrary element } g \in J , \ g(a_1,\dots , a_n)=0 \}$.

It seems to me that it should be $I(V(J)) \subset J$, because it includes the condition that the polynomial in $J$ will vanish at some point in $V(J)$.

Can someone show me the inclusion, explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think this through again. $I(V(J))$ is the set of polynomials that vanish on every point on which every element of $J$ vanishes. Certainly every element of $J$ vanishes on every point on which every element of $J$ vanishes. On the other hand, $x$ vanishes on every point on which $x^2$ vanishes, but isn't in the ideal generated by $x^2$.

Comment: How would you write it in set theory notation, i.e a proof in the formalism $g \in J \Rightarrow g \in I(V(J))$?

Comment: I wouldn't. There's no reason to do so; do indicate if something in the proof I've written is unclear. If you really want to write this needlessly formally, which may be the reason you were confused in the first place, then just rewrite "is" as $=$, "for all" as $\forall$, "then" as $\implies$, and so on, in my answer.

Comment: So if $g\in J$, and necessarily it vanishes in some closed algebraically field, k, it vanishes at the same points of $V(J)$, thus $g \in I(V(J))$; Is this the right formalism?

Comment: I don't see why you want to start talking about the field. If $g\in J$, then $g(a_1...a_n)=0$ for $(a_1...a_n)\in V(J)$, because $V(J)$ is the points of $k^n$ at which all the elements of $J$ vanish.

Answer (score 1):

We show that $$J \subseteq \sqrt J \subseteq I(V(J)).$$

That $J \subseteq \sqrt J$ is immediate.

That $\sqrt J \subseteq I(V(J))$ follows from: Let $f \in \sqrt J$, then $f^n \in J$ for some $n > 0$. But $V(J) = \{P \in \mathbb A^n : g(P) = 0$ for all $g \in J\}$ and $f^n \in J$, so $f^n(P) = 0$ for all $P \in V(J)$. But $0 = f^n(P) = \big(f(P)\big)^n$ and since $A = k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is an integral domain, then $f(P) = 0$. Hence $f \in I(V(J))$.

Notice that if you had the Nullstellensatz at your disposal, you would have the stronger result: $$J \subseteq \sqrt J = I(V(J)).$$